# Use AngularJS controller scope property in directive when property isn't available in directive link phase

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a view with a call to a directive on it. In this directive I want to use a property of the controller scope. However this property isn't set yet when the directives link function runs because it's set on the return of a resource call.

How can use the property value in the directive when it is available from the Resource result?

I curerntly have:

```
        .directive('meImageUpload', ['$parse', '$compile', function ($parse, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                imageUploadType: '=imageUploadType',
                imageUploadId: '=imageUploadId'
            },
```

and

```
<div me-image-upload image-upload-type="'quote'" image-upload-id="record.Id"></div>
```

but this results in imageUploadId always being undefined.

Comment: The `record.Id` is part of the data the are loaded from a resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you try to do things with you `imageUploadId`, but it is set to late? This should be no problem, as the attributes you you connected with your scope definition are bound in both ways. Therefore you can use the `scope.$watch` function.

```
scope.$watch("imageUploadId", function (newId, oldId) {
    // here you can use the parameter id newId or read the new one from the scope
    doSomething($scope.imageUploadId);
}
```

If the value (`record.id`) changed in your controller scope it is also updated automatically in the directive, because you connected them with `imageUploadId: '=imageUploadId'`. In that case you could also use the shorthand `imageUploadId: '='`, because they have the same names.